# Misunderstanding in billing of Reserved instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I launched a m3.medium reserved instance yesterday, but the usage is already 163hrs and charge me 5 dollars, what does it mean by the usage of that amount of hours?

ps: I launched one on-demand instance before, but I just ran it for 2 hours and stopped it. After purchasing the reserved instance, I restarted it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see amazon's billing documentation for an explanation of this pricing.

http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/purchasing-options/reserved-instances/

> Light and Medium Utilization Reserved Instances also are billed by the instance-hour for the time that instances are in a running state; if you do not run the instance in an hour, there is zero usage charge. Partial instance-hours consumed are billed as full hours. Heavy Utilization Reserved Instances are billed for every hour during the entire Reserved Instance term (which means you’re charged the hourly fee regardless of whether any usage has occurred during an hour).